# Styling of h2 tag does not seem to be working

Tags: html, css

I just added a style for an H2 tag like this:

```
h2.section_header
{
    color: #1C1C1C;
    font-family:gisha,serif;
}
```

and in my HTML I am trying to reference it like this:

```
<h2 clas="section_header">Most Popular Problems</h2>
```

But it does not seem to be changing the color to the one I specified.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mis-spelled `class` in the tag.

Comment: just fixed that typo, but it still does not seem to be displaying that color.  Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: Since your chosen colour is very close to black, are you sure? Have you tried putting white or something?

Comment: good point, just tried green and it rendered.  Thanks - will accept answer whenever the site lets me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<h2 clas="section_header"
```

This has a typo in and should read:

```
<h2 class="section_header"
```

Comment: thanks - I just fixed the typo but it is still not rendering the color. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Genadinik: It looks like you have found the answer

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code "font-family" is the right code to style a font/characters.

The other behavior of "font-family" is trying to style the font/characters of your **first declared font family** which is "**geisha**". **If** your computer does not support of that font style. The **second declared font family** will be used which is "**serif**".

Sans serif, serif and monospace are the **generic font family** which is supported to all computers.